# Return/Cancel Order - Shopping Cart

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, shopping-cart, google-checkout, authorize.net

1. I have implemented the Custom Shopping Cart in my site. My site
   allowed paying the amount in three different checkouts.

   a. Google 

   b. PayPal 

   c. Authorize.Net
2. Once customers place an order they can view their order details and status from Order Management page. I have defined two processes

   a. If payment is success      - Customer can Return the Order. 

   b. if payment is declined/pending - Customer can Cancel the Order.

My questions

How can i process the "Cancel Order" if buyer requested. Can i programmatically handle this process and stop the payment process in payment gateway (Google, Paypal and so)

Return Order

1. a.  Can i programmatically handle this process and return the payment
   to buyer account from payment gateway (Google, PayPal and so).

   b.  Buyer can request a return to Merchant. Merchant will process and
   return the order manually (Already implemented)

Thanks,
Velu

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? I have no idea what you actually want; do you want to know how to process refunds on all three gateways? Or do you want to handle chargebacks efficiently?

Comment: After google it i was able to found the information

Paypal

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/nvp_RefundTransaction_cs.txt
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APRefund
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_soap_r_RefundTransaction
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_RefundTransaction


Authorize.NET 

http://www.authorize.net/support/AIM_guide.pdf(Page No :15)

Thanks to all for reply.\

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the questions correctly you are looking for an API to programatically cancel and refund orders.

Please have a look at the Checkout Notification and Order Processing APIs. You can use those APIs to receive order information and update order fulfillment status (e.g charge, ship, refund, cancel). You'll need to implement a service that can communicate with Google's servers.

More information in this doc:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Processing.html

Comment: After google it i was able to found the information

Paypal

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/nvp_RefundTransaction_cs.txt
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APRefund
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_soap_r_RefundTransaction
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_RefundTransaction


Authorize.NET 

http://www.authorize.net/support/AIM_guide.pdf(Page No :15)

Thanks to all for reply.